# How to redistribute/force points into a grid so moving amount is minimal?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, point

I have a set of `n×n` points with float coordinates in the range of [0..n]. How to assign a grid point to each point from the set so the "sum of movement needed" is minimal - Without using brute force?

[image: points and grid]
(sum to minimize = sum of the lengths of the arrows)

The algorithm I came up with:

```
for all remaining points in the set
    calculate distances to each point's nearest available grid point
    place point with smallest distance on its near grid point
    remove that point from the set
    make grid point unavailable
repeat.
```

Now, I suspect this is a pretty standard algorithm which I just couldn't find the right search keywords for, as you can probably tell from my flawed terminology.

Or should this already be the best way?

Answer (score 0):

This is a [Linear Programming Assignment Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem).

It can be solved by making a distance matrix of `n*n x n*n` and then solve using [Hungarian Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm).

Compute the distance matrix by calculating the distance of each point from each of the grid locations. Then assign a unique grid to each point so as to minimize the total distance. Hungarian Algorithm does that in polynomial time.

Comment: Looks pretty good, I'll report back as soon as I implement it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the voronoi diagram. Then compute the average cell and use it for the grid.